# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc for two independent query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I found that there are some related issue on mysqi_fetch_assoc online.
But my question is different from them, I do not execute two similar query or loop similar array, so not data_seek pointer helps.

Please hear me out, I have two different queries, execute on two different tables, so they are independent. Then I noticed that the second query will never been properly executed.   I tried switching both queries then noticed that only first one will be execute.
So I created 'myArrayA' to store some information, so I could know where and how it caused that, that's when I noticed the second while loop will be entirely being skipped, with the if else statement, so no '$sql' will be assigned to.

I also tried changing one of the mysqi_fetch_assoc to mysqi_fetch_array, still the same. Is it the referencing problem ?
I am new to this, kindly let me know if there is any document I overlooked,that there is some similar issue with solution, I will close the question if there is any.

P/S: I can update the full query if it is needed when I am back to work

```
 $sql_A = "some query from table A;";
 $result_A = mysqli_query($con, $sql_A);

 while($row_A = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_A)){
 if ($row_A['myguest'] == "")
 {       
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, $row_A['myguest']);
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "if in rowA");

      $sql = "query;";
 }
 else 
 {
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, $row_A['myguest']);
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "else in rowA");

      $sql = "query;";
 }
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "result A in");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, $sql);
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, $row->something);
      array_push(($mystdclass->infoArray, array(something from the query);
 }

 array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "A out");
 $sql_B = "some query on table B;";
 $result_B = mysqli_query($con, $sql_B);
 array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, $sql_B);

 while($row_B = mysqli_fetch_object($result_B)){
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "before B while");

      if ($row_B['mycustomer'] == "")
      {
           array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "cust if in");           
           $sql_cust = "some query;";

      }
      else 
      {
           array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "cust else ");
           $sql_cust = "query;";
      }
 }
 $result_cust = mysqli_query($con, $sql_cust);
 array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "cust end while in");
 array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, $sql_cust);
 while($row_cust = mysqli_fetch_object($result_cust)){
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "whats here");
      array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, $row_cust->somethingcustomer);
      array_push($mystdclass->customer_group, array(some array in B));
  }

 array_push($mystdclass->myArrayA, "out out");
```

Comment: PHP doesn’t skip while loops willy-nilly; if your’s doesn’t run a single time, then the fetch did only return false on the first call already. Check the actual number of records the query returned.

Comment: You've abstracted too much in this question, and too little in the code structure. Define some functions for querying and populating your result structures, and do some more error checking of course. If the $sql_* queries are interdependent after all, you should use some status flags rather than divert in the loops. (Overall doesn't look answerable at the moment.)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It should not be that hard to use some vardumps or to run your code with XDebug enabled